# how to transfer data from edittext to spinner both are in different activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activity..In 1st activity i have 2 button 1st button is to start 2nd activity and 2nd button is to start 3rd activity.The 2nd activity containing edittext and button.The 3rd activity containing Spinner.I want to transfer data from edittext to spinner

[1 activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBtiG.jpg)

[2 activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTO61.jpg)

[3 activity][3]

first activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String resultStr = data.getStringExtra("result");
            item=resultStr;
        }
    }
}

public void start1(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Task.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
public void start2(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Spinner.class);
    intent .putExtra("send_data",item);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

second activity:

```
public class Task extends Activity {
Button btnAdd;
EditText subject;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add) ;


    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String content = subject.getText().toString();
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result",content);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

third activity:

```
public class Spinner extends Activity {
android.widget.Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
SharedPreferences sharedPref;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);
    spinner = (android.widget.Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> savedStringSet = sharedPref.getStringSet("SpinnerData", null);
    if (savedStringSet != null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>(savedStringSet);
    }

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Spinner.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("SELECT AN ITEM");
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                   int position, long id) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("send_data");
        list.add(value);
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Spinner.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("SpinnerData", new HashSet<String>(list));
    editor.apply();
}
```

Error:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
                                                                              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
                                                                              at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:429)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: some infos needed: You want to use SQLite? You want to make infos available all over the app? You have any preference on how to store datas? only for one use or for next use also?

Comment: i dont need sqlite n all..i want it for one use only like through bundle n all

Comment: Done a sample in the code below, not exactly a copy-paste code but you have all you need :)

Answer (score 1):

First part is taking back a result from the 2nd activity to the 1st activity.

For this I took [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/4700782). You can read it below.

> From your `FirstActivity` call the `SecondActivity` using 
>   `startActivityForResult()` method
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
> startActivityForResult(i, 1);
> ```
>
> In your `SecondActivity` set the data which you want to return back to
>   `FirstActivity`. If you don't want to return back, don't set any.
>
> For example: In secondActivity if you want to send back data:
>
> ```
> Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
> returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
> setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
> finish();
> ```
>
> If you don't want to return data:
>
> ```
> Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
> setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
> finish();
> ```
>
> Now in your FirstActivity class write following code for the
>   `onActivityResult()` method.
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>
>     if (requestCode == 1) {
>         if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
>             String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
>         }
>         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
>             //Write your code if there's no result
>         }
>     }
> }//onActivityResult
> ```

The second part is done by passing this data from the first activity to the 3rd activity.

You can do this by doing the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
intent .putExtra("key",result);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the 3rd activity you can use:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
intent .putExtra("key",result);

Comment: @Badprince as i wrote, it's not a "ready to use" solution. have a look at some samples on the internet and try yourself. we don't have your code neither your log, so try looking on google and investigate so you can find solution yourself

Comment: @Badprince if there is any error in the code please notify me. I don't have a compiler now so it might be not perfect

Comment: the application crashes when i click 2 button

Comment: see my edited question i posted my code hope get a help from you i am stuck in this from 2 to 3 days :)

Comment: @Badprince need 2 infos: 1) which is the 2 button? 2) can you add in your question the stacktrace? (it's the detailed error)

Comment: I edited my question and posted the error please look out:)

Comment: @Badprince thanks, one last information: can you debug your code checking wich line exactly throws the error? is it the adapter creation or the "setAdapter" or something else?

Comment: @Badprince wait, in the last setAdapter, under the if check, you are passing a list instead of an array. fix this and should work!

Comment: Bro list is a object name of a arraylist above i have created in that array object i have pass the bundle object that's y list is there in the last

Comment: @Badprince list and arraylist are pretty much the same. try converting this arraylist into an array and see if it works, btw i repeat: post the line throwing the error pls

Comment: its not specifying any line which is throwing error

Comment: i got the following error thats it i have a code which work great in single activity like both spinner and editfield in same activity its work great but while i am trying to separate it this happen

Comment: @Badprince you can find the line with debugging. you put a breakpoint in the first line of oncreate and you step row by row. one will throw an error, no?

Comment: @Badprince nullpointer, maybe i got it: check if "send_data" is null. you never check it and it's not sure it is not null

Comment: i did same problem..:(

Comment: @Badprince unfortunatly if you want more help, you have to provide us the line throwing the error

Comment: you dont have a compiler or what ?

Comment: @Badprince 1) I don't have a compiler 2) even if I have be sure i wouldn't create a project with all your pages and controllers only to do something you are too lazy to do

Answer (score 0):

You can finish your second activity passing edittext data to first activity with onActivityResult.
Then you can launch your third activity passing your edittext data to it.
Then in your third activity you can populate dinamically your spinner data.

If i can suggest you, spinner is an old api, let's use something better as a list in a dialogfragment

Comment: can u elobrate properly i am a newbiee :)